# Conditional LEFT Excel formula (or VBA?) based on formula results?

Tags: excel, vba

I have in Column C2, formula results which I need to perform LEFT on in order to trim the cell formula value

1. The formula result MUST have one of the following (. OR _ OR -) in answer
2. If one of the above exists in the cell , then LEFT(C2,FIND("the_variable_in_the_formula_answer),C2)-1)

My VBA isn't the best, but I think I could use

```
 variable = Left(Sheet1.[C2],InStr(Sheet1.[C2],".")-1)
```

I don't know how to make the .(period) , _(underscore) OR -(hyphen) a variable to look for

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula at row two and fill down the column:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(Sheet1!C2, AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH({".","-","_"},Sheet1!C2),1)-1), "")
```

It truncates until the **first found** of `{".","-","_"}`. If you want to truncate till the last found, change `15` into `14`.

---

For your additional requirements:

```
=IF(ISNA(C2), D2,
  IFERROR(LEFT(Sheet1!C2,AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH({".","-","_"},Sheet1!C2),1)-1),C2))
```

Comment: Works like a champ! One wrinkle, however, how would I tell the formula that (and there are like only two dozen of these in column D) IF there is anything other than #N/A in Column D (like D2 or D3 as we copy the formula down) to place that value? There will not be anything in C2 other than #N/A if there is a no error value in D2

Comment: @Mike try `=IF(ISNA(C2), D2, initialFormulaHere)`. Or you may try replacing the last `""` in the initial formula by `D2`.

Comment: Hmm.. still having an issue. Where there is no ("." , "_" , "-") then it exits I assume. Which is exactly what we told it to do. Can we modify this so that if there is no error AND none of the search strings, then use the value?